# Upgrading Hive to allow Update/Delete Transactions within Ambari

Tags: hive, hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

I have created a Hadoop Cluster with Ambari 2.1 including Hive. I would like to be able to do Update and Delete queries within Hive, but it looks like I currently have version 0.12.0.2.0 of Hive. I would like to upgrade to 0.13 or 0.14 to enable these transactions, but I am not sure how to do that with an existing installation of Ambari. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you could do a rolling upgrade by downloading all the new packages.

Comment: For others' information, I actually had hive version 1.2..., not 0.12. I ended up changing the configurations to allow for Update/Delete Transactions with the [modify config script](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AMBARI/Modify+configurations)

Answer (score 0):

I think you could follow the HDP docs from hortonworks website

[Manual Upgrade of HDP](http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/Ambari-2.1.0.0/bk_upgrading_Ambari/content/_upgrading_the_hdp_stack_from_21_to_23.html)

[Upgrading Stack](http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP1/HDP-1.2.3/bk_hdp1-system-admin-guide/content/sys-admin-guide-4.html) - Ambari

[Performing upgrade](http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/Ambari-2.1.0.0/bk_upgrading_Ambari/content/_complete_the_upgrade_21-23.html) - Hortonworks

Hope this is helpful.

P.S: Upgrades/ Inserts are not supported in 0.13. You will have to have 0.14 or later for the same.